# if L = P ∩ Q where P is Context Free Language(CFL) and Q is Regular then L is in?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, automata

The intersection of a `context free language P` with a `regular language Q`, is said to be always `context free`,but I still don't get why it is context free but not regular.

The language generated by such an intersection has strings that are accepted both by a `PDA` and a `DFA` .Since all regular language are context free and it is accepted by a DFA, shouldn't it be a `regular language`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of all strings from an alphabet is a regular language, and its intetsection with any other language *L* from that alphabet is precisely *L*.

Or in other words, it is not just which strings are accepted. Also relevant is which strings are not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The following lemmas are well known.

Lemma 2.1 If L is a context free language without e then there is grammar in Chomsky

Normal

Form that generates L.

Lemma 2.2 If L = ∅ and L is regular then L is the union of regular language A1,...,An

where

each Ai is accepted by a DFA with exactly one ﬁnal state.

We now prove our main theorem.

Theorem 2.3 If L1 is a context free language and L2 is a regular language then L1 ∩L2 is

context

free.

Proof:

We do the case where e ∈/ L1 and L2 = ∅. All other cases we leave to the reader.

ByLemma2.1wecanassumethereexistsaChomskynormalformgrammarG = (N,Σ,S,P)

for L1. By Lemma 2.2 L2 = A1 ∪___∪An where each Ai where each Ai is recognized by

a DFA

with exactly one ﬁnal state. Note that

```
         L1 ∩L2 = L1 ∩(A1 ∪___∪An) = U(L1 ∩Ai).

                                         i=1
```

Since CFL’s are closed under union (and this can be proven using CFG’s, so this is not a

cheat)

we need only show that the intersection of L1 with a regular language recognized by a DFA

with

one ﬁnal state is CFL. Let M = (Q,Σ,δ,s,{f}) be a DFA with exactly one ﬁnal state.

We construct the CFG G0 = (N0,Σ,S0,P0) for L1 ∩L(M).

1. The nonterminals N0 are triples [p,V,r] where V ∈ N and p,r ∈ Q.
2. For each production A → BC in P, for every p,q,r ∈ Q we have the production

[p,A,r] → [p,B,q][q,C,r]

in P0.

3. For every production A → σ in P, for every (p,σ,q) ∈ Q×Σ×Q such that δ(p,σ) = q we

have the production

in P0

4. S0 = [s,S,f]

[p,A,q] → σ